# Chrome forces to https on .dev and won't honor local secure certs

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

I'm trying to go to `http://example.dev` on my local. Every time I do this, Chrome redirects me to `https` thanks to Google's new purchase of the `.dev` gTLD.

My local `.dev` domains have secure certs created at the time vagrant is provisioned. However, since Chrome 63, it now gives the SSL error `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

What is wrong with my secure cert that Chrome refuses to allow it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I'm using the `.dev` domain for development. It's relevant because changes to Chrome are impacting a commonly used development practice.

Comment: In summary: you are using a toplevel domain which belongs to someone else (Google) and was not designed to be free for everybody to use. Thus you either need to stop using this domain or adhere to the policy of the owner, i.e. use HTTPS.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm already using HTTPS. That isn't the problem. The problem is that Google is not accepting my secure certs due to the error I specified.

Comment: @eComEvo: NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID - it looks like your certificate is not signed by a trusted authority (self-signed?). And with HSTS it is not possible to ignore such errors to accept the certificate.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich that answers the question. I'm not buying a secure cert for every potentially temporary development domain so migrating all `.dev` to `.test` seems like the only way to go.